Meaning of ずっと飼っておけんぐらい
I line spoken by Hagrid in the Japanese translation of Harry Potter:

「俺もずっと飼っておけんぐらいのことはわかっとる。」
"I know I can't keep him forever" (original text)

Harry is trying to persuade Hagrid to get rid of the dragon he is raising.
There's obviously a contraction going on in 飼っておけんぐらい but I'm not certain what it is. I assume it must be 飼っておけないぐらい.
If so, I'm struggling to understand what ぐらい is doing here. How would it differ from 俺もずっと飼っておけないことはわかっとる
My guess is that it is qualifying ずっと and hence adding emphasis to 'forever', e.g. "I can't keep him (for as long as) forever (but I can at least keep him for a few weeks)." Does this sound right?

You're right that 飼っておけん means 飼っておけない. Technically I believe ん is a contraction not of ない but of ぬ, but the meaning is the same.
ぐらい isn't emphasizing ずっと. It's used to express that ずっと飼っておけん is something small or obvious; that Hagrid can at least admit that. This definition from デジタル大辞泉 seems relevant:

（多く「くらいなら」の形で）事実・状態を示して、程度を軽いもの、または重いものとして強く主張する意を表す。「簡単に否決される—なら、提案しなければよかった」

